# Trying to remove bullets from this List in CSS

Tags: css

Here's my code:

```
ul.top-ten li:before {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'fontello';
    content: '\f08e';
    margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
    color: #ff9900;
}
```

I thought this line would strip the bullets away:

```
list-style-type: none;
```

However, no joy.

Here's the HTML:

```
  <ul class="top-ten">
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Pears</li>
    <li>Lemons</li>
    <li>Peaches</li>
  </ul>
```

So all good right? Apparently not...the bullets are still there...any idea why?

Comment: You need to set for ul scope instead of li

Comment: Apply it to `ul.top-ten` instead of `ul.top-ten li:before`

Comment: Remove `li:before` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"list-style-type" property is applicable on the ul item type. I guess you are trying to add some content for each list item using the before pseudo selector. What you need to do move list-style-type: none; property to ul.top-ten selector.

```
ul.top-ten {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.top-ten li:before {
    font-family: 'fontello';
    content: '\f08e';
    margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
    color: #ff9900;
}
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, list-style-type needs adding to `ul` not `li` ([css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/list-style/))

```
ul.top-ten {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'fontello';
    content: '\f08e';
    margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
    color: #ff9900;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add to your li tag list-style: none;

```
ul li{
   list-style: none;
}
```